# Detect a transition in or out of daylight savings time with Delphi

Tags: delphi, timezone, detect, dst

I need to trigger an event when the PC transitions into or out of daylight savings time.  I could monitor the current state with GetTimezoneInformation and check it every second waiting for a change, but I just thought there might be a simpler way that didn't involve continuous checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1469513.php
windows doesn't send a WM_TIMECHANGE on daylight savings event. Workarounds(I didn't use any of them, so I'm not sure if it works):

- check the local time every few seconds or so (yuck)
- change your calculations to be based on GMT
- watch the
  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias
  value by using RegNotifyChangeKeyValue() (this value changes when there is a
  DST transition as well as when the time zone changes).

Best regards, 
Radu

Comment: The missing WM_TIMECHANGE seems to be restricted to Win2K systems as some posts suggest. Here somebody tested it successfully with Windows XP: http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/forums/windows-xp/clock-change-notification-dst-change-206150.html

Comment: App is WinXP/Win7 so I'll code the WM_TIMECHANGE event and see if it works on W7.

Answer (score 2):

The [Delphi TZDB](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-tzdb/) helps you keep track of the algorithms on when a transition should have occurred.

--jeroen

Comment: Because the rules change, I would start with Jeroen's suggestions, but make those values inputs into your algorithm, so it is configurable.

Answer (score -2):

For the UK at least (not sure of other countries) the transition only occurs on a Sunday morning so that could help reduce the frequency of your checks to just a few hours of each week. Additionally (for the UK again) this always occurs on the last weekend of March and October so you can further reduce the period for which you need to perform checks.

If you can collect the rules for each country that you are interested in and code their logic then that will obviously be more efficient than a continuous check but of course you are then responsible for being correct rather than relying on the OS.

Comment: The DST rules can change frequently, so I wouldn't go for maintaining them manually. Interesting to read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/24/55413.aspx. Quote: "[...] the laws regarding daylight savings time are in constant flux."

Comment: -1 This is bad advice. You need to rely on the system to do this for you.

Comment: @David, I feel that is a bit harsh - certainly the "only check on weekends" optimisation is correct for DST for all of Europe, USA and Canada (including when rules have changed, such as when the US moved by a week a few years back).  Equally the 2am rule can be used reliably for these regions. Polling every second 24x7 is needlessly inefficient. I also placed a caveat on the 2nd paragraph so it isn't as if I gave mindless advice suggesting that you could do better than OS vendors.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I've already dealt with the issues of detecting if we are in DST or not.  What the client wants is an event to be logged when a transition occurs.